# How to get the list of sub folder in a SharePoint Document library updated atleast before 30 days

Tags: sharepoint

I want to get all the Title of the sub-folder which are modified at least before 30 days in a SharePoint Document library

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and edit your question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use caml query to get all the sub folders. Where Modified date less than your date and greater than your date. ViewAttributes recursiveall.